# Which senrence is correct?

Tags: grammar

Above mentioned Goods were received in good condition.
(OR)
Above mentioned Goods have been received in good condition.

Comment: It seems you've already asked the question before. Please include more context and research in your post. Also, try searching our site for more information, as we have many questions asking about the difference. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Comment: Also see [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer) and [Can I ask a question for the second time?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/can-i-ask-a-question-for-the-second-time).